# I use Python 2.7, Windows 7 64-bit -- alternatives to Psyco?

Tags: psyco

Apparently Psyco doesn't work for Python 2.7.

Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Motivation: use psyco to accelerate pydev's debugger on windows

Comment: If the motivation was the pydev debugger, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015390/speedup-pydev-debugging-on-python-2-6/9034400#9034400

Answer (score 3):

Today's state of the art in Python compilation is [PyPy](http://pypy.org/). I don't have any information about whether it will work for you on your target platform.

Comment: pypy does not work on 64bit windows (yet), but you can run a 32bit version there

Comment: @fijal - to be exact: pypy 32bit works both on windows 64bit and windows 32bit

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no real alternative only using Python as psyco does (Pypy which is increasingly becoming the 'only Python' alternative doesn't support extension modules, so, right now, many of projects can't migrate, but if yours isn't one of those, it can be a nice approach)

If you can't use Pypy right now, after doing a profile session and confirming things can't be speed up anymore in plain Python, the path is usually one of:

1. c/c++ extension module (my personal favorite -- works on any platform and using boost::python makes this process pretty simple and straightforward, although if you don't know c/c++, this may not be so easy).
2. Cython (you usually have to change your program a bit so that it becomes fast in Cython, and the changes aren't really python code, but an extension of it)
3. Shed Skin (if it can cope with your program)