# Speedup pydev debugging on python 2.6+

Tags: python, performance, debugging, pydev, psyco

[PyDev](http://pydev.org/) reports it can use [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) to speed its debugger. However the [most up-to-date psyco build I found](http://sourceforge.net/projects/psyco/files/psyco/1.6/) for windows was for python 2.5.
Is there a way to speed-up pydev debugging, either with or without psyco, with newer 2.x versions such as 2.6 and 2.7?

In [this relevant yet unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599162/i-use-python-2-7-windows-7-64-bit-alternatives-to-psyco) there's a reference to [pypy](http://pypy.org/), could that be encorporated somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, psyco seems unsupported at this time (its main developer went to work on pypy).

Pypy itself seems like a good choice if your program can run with it (many modules are currently unsupported in it -- especially modules using a c/c++ extension, so, although that may change in the future, it's unrealistic for many projects right now).

Still, in most of the use-cases, the debugger should work fast enough (a lot of time was spent optimizing it), and in the seldom use cases where it gets slow, the Remote Debugger ( http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html ) can be used -- that way the program can run at max speed until it reaches a breakpoint in code.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the remote debugger, which reduces the need for psyco debugger. Thanks!